# Given that $g(x) = 2f(x) + x^2 + 4$ and $f(1) = -24$, how many real roots of the equation $g(x) = 0$ are there on the interval $[-3; 3]$?

Tags: functions

> Consider function $f(x)$ whose derivative is continuous on the interval $[-3; 3]$ and the graph of the function $y = f'(x)$ is pictured below. Given that $g(x) = 2f(x) + x^2 + 4$ and $f(1) = -24$, how many real roots of the equation $g(x) = 0$ are there on the interval $[-3; 3]$?

[image]

[For context, this question is taken from an exam whose format consists of 50 multiple-choice questions with a time limit of 90 minutes. Calculators are the only electronic device allowed in the testing room. (You know those scientific calculators sold at stationery stores and sometimes bookstores? They are the goods.) I need a solution that works within these constraints. Thanks for your cooperation, as always. (Do I need to sound this professional?)

By the way, if the wording of the problem sounds rough, sorry for that. I'm not an expert at translating documents.]

Excuse my waterlogged, dropped-on-the-floor-too-many-times, memory-of-a-goldfish-with-dementia brick camera quality.

Anyhow, first of all, $g(1) = 2f(1) + 1^2 + 4 = -43$ and $$g'(x) = 0 \iff 2[f'(x) + x] = 0 \iff \left[ \begin{aligned} x &= -3\\ x &= 1\\ x&= 3 \end{aligned} \right.$$

From which, we can draw the table of variations (*in glorious Technicolor*).

[image]

Now, we just need to know whether $2f(\pm 3) + 13$ are greater than zero. And this is where I have a problem. How am I supposed to know?

Perhaps it's through the values of $\displaystyle \int_1^{\pm 3}f'(x)\, \mathrm dx = f(\pm 3) - f(1)$, which could be somewhat perceived in the graph itself, but I am not entirely sure.

Anyhow, thanks for reading, (and even more if you could help~)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is best attacked by intuition.  You can leave the formal analysis in the drawer.

$g'(x) = 2f'(x) + 2x.$

$g(1) = -43.$

As $x$ goes from $-1$ to $1$, you have that

$f'(x)$ takes on the values from about $(-4.3)$ to $(-1)$.

So the *typical* value of $f'(x)$ in this interval is about $(-2.8)$.

So, the typical value of $g'(x)$ in this interval is about $(-5.5)$.

This implies that $g(-1)$ is about $-(31)$, which is nowhere near the $x$-axis.  So, in the interval $-1 \leq x \leq 1$, $g(x)$ never crosses (i.e. comes near) the $x$-axis.

Similar considerations apply for $1 \leq x \leq 3$.

For $(-2.5) \leq x \leq -1$, $f'(x)$ has a typical value of about $(-3)$.

This implies that the typical value of $g'(x)$ in this interval is about $(-6) + (-4) = (-10)$.  So, since $g(-1)$ is estimated to be around $(-31)$, you can estimate $g(-2.5)$ to be around $(-16)$.

This means that for $-2.5 \leq x \leq -1, g(x)$ again comes nowhere near the $x$-axis.

Further, with $g(-2.5)$ estimated to be around $(-16)$, and with $g'(x)$ not that small (i.e. not that negative) in the interval of $-3 \leq x \leq -2.5$, you also have that $g(x)$ does not cross the $x$-axis for $-3 \leq x \leq -2.5$.

What this means is that by eyeballing the behavior of $f'(x)$, using the fact that $g'(x) = 2f'(x) + 2x$, and using the fact that $g(1) = -43$, you conclude that $g(x)$ does not come near the $x$-axis,for $-3 \leq x \leq 3.$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Since it is agreed that $ \ g(1) \ = \ -43 \ \ $ and that $ \ g'(x) \ =  \ 2·f'(x) + 2x \ \ , $  we can pick out a few "landmarks" that permit us to "sketch" the derivative function $ \ g'(x) \ \   $ [the violet curve in the "stretched" graph at right above], noting marked values of $ \ f'(x) \ $ or its axial-intercepts or near approach "below" the $ \ x-$axis.  You already observed that $ \ g'(-3) \ = \ g'(1) \ = \ g'(3) \ = \ 0 \ \ . $ The lowest value of the derivative is somewhere *near* $ \ g'(-1) \ \sim \ 2·(-4) + (2·[-1]) \ = \ -10 \ \ $ and the largest value, *near*   $ \ x \ =  \ +2 \ , \ $ is less than $ \ 2·0 + (2·2) \ = \ 4 \ \ . $

[image]

Since this *is* a sketch, we can approximate the "net change" in $ \ g(x) \  $ by the areas "under" two parabolas, one with intercepts $ \ x \ = \ -3 \ $ and $ \ x \ = \ +1 \ $ and thus with vertex $ \ ( -1 \ , \ -10) \ \ , $ the other with intercepts $ \ x \ = \ +1 \ $ and $ \ x \ = \ +3 \ \ , \ $ and so having the vertex $ \ ( +2 \ , \ 4) \ \ . \ $  The equations of these parabolas are then $ \ y \ = \ -10 + \ \frac52(x+1)^2 \ $ and $ \ y \ = \ 4 - 4(x-2)^2 \ \ . $

So the net change from $ \ x \ = \ -3 \ $ to  $ \ x \ = \ +1 \ $ is somewhat smaller in absolute-value that $$ \ \int_{-3}^1 \   -10 + \ \frac52(x+1)^2 \ \ dx \ \ = \ \ -10x \ + \ \frac56(x+1)^3\vert_{-3}^1 $$ $$ = \ \ -10 \ - \ 30 \ + \ \frac{40}{6} \ + \  \frac{40}{6} \ \ = \ \ -\frac{80}{3} \ \ , $$
while the net change from $ \ x \ = \ +1 \ $ to  $ \ x \ = \ +3 \ $ is less than $$ \ \int^3_1 \   4 - \ 4(x-2)^2 \ \ dx \ \ = \ \ 4x \ - \ \frac43(x-2)^3\vert_1^3 \ \ = \ \ 12 \ - \ 4 \ - \ \frac{4}{3} \ - \  \frac{4}{3} \ \ = \ \ \frac{16}{3} \ \ . $$

Hence, the function $ \ g(x) \ $ has *decreased* by something less than $ \ 27 \ $ in passing from $ \ x \ = \ -3 \ $ t0 $ \ x \ = \ +1 \ \ , $ where it attains the value $ \ g(1) \ = \ -43 \ \ , \ $ and only *increases* by an amount less than $ \ 6 \ $ for $ \ g(3) \ \ . $  So it is apparent that $ \ g(x) \ < \ 0 \ $ on the interval $ \ [-3 \ , \ +3] \ \ . $

We could possibly by-pass this much calculation by observing that the average value of $ \ g'(x) \ $ on $ \ [-3 \ , \ +1 ] \ $ would need to be $ \ \frac{0 - 43}{1 \ - \ [-3]} \ < \ -10 \ $ in order for $ \ g(-3) \ $ to "become as large" as zero.  This would require the average value of $ \ f'(x) \ $ to be $ \ 2·\langle f'(x) \rangle - \ \frac{2-6}{2} \ \sim \ -10 \ \Rightarrow \ \langle f'(x) \rangle \ \sim \ -3 \ \ , $ which it clearly is not.  Likewise, the average value of $ \ g'(x) \ $ over $ \ [+1 \ , \ +3] \ $ would have to be $ \ \frac{0 - [-43]}{3 \ - \ 1} \ > \ +20 \ , $  which would call for $ \ 2·\langle f'(x) \rangle + \ \frac{2+6}{2} \ \sim \ +20 \ \Rightarrow \ \langle f'(x) \rangle \ \sim \ +8 \ \ . $